# CLng function return funny value

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code in a legacy excel file

```
CLng("&O" & "210") 

returns  136
```

what is the use of this "&O"?

I am struggling to understand

please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The &o indicates an octal (base 8) number:

Octal 210 = Decimal 136

&o210 = (2 × 8²) + (1 × 8¹) + (0 × 8⁰) = 136

The same concept applies to hexadecimal (base 16):

Hex A1 = Decimal 161

&hA1 = (10 × 16¹) + (1 × 16⁰) = 161   (Hex values are 0-9,A,B,C,D,E,F)

Comment: What about &H? can you provide information; like above?